# What does "allow seven sittings" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's from [A Little Java, a Few Patterns](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=7BWvrY1zPtoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Do not rush through this book. **Allow seven sittings**, at least. Read
>   carefully. Mark up the book or take notes; valuable hints are
>   scattered throughout the text. Work through the examples, don't scan
>   them. Keep in mind the motto "Think first, experiment later."

So, what is the meaning of `Allow seven sittings` in given context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to "sit down to read and study" in seven separate sessions (taking a break between them).
I suppose to let the material sink in, so as to not rush through it.

In this phrase, [***sitting***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sitting) means:

> 3) a period of being seated at some activity"   ⇒ *to read a book in two sittings*"

Comment: Could you please explain the etymology of `Allow seven sittings`? I mean, How does `"sit down to read and study" in seven separate sessions` come from `Allow seven sittings`?

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: Also mention the word "allow" means "make time for" or "plan for."